# html columns fit content but match heights when side by side (without jQuery)

Tags: html, css, flexbox, zurb-foundation

I have 3 divs with different amount of content. I want the divs to match in heights because of their backgrounds. My question is how to achieve this with pure html/css without jQuery/Javascript, if possible.

When small, each div becomes 12 columns so their heights fit the content. When medium, the green and blue are the same heights. When large, the grey box matches the height of the blue and green divs.

https://jsfiddle.net/Ljzr2krv/

```css
.col-1 {
  background-color: blue;
}
.col-2 {
  background-color: green;
}
.col-3 {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.1/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row collapse">
  <div class="large-3 small-12 columns">
    <div class="row collapse">
      <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-12 columns col-1">
      The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
      </div>
      <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-12 columns col-2">
      The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="large-9 small-12 columns col-3">
  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: This is what I'm trying to get as an end result.]

Currently, in order to achieve this, I have been using jQuery to grab the divs' natural heights, and assign the larger of the heights depending on the window size. This is calling every time the window resizes as well.

I am hoping for an html/css solution that could achieve this arrangement of divs while allowing the heights of the div's to align like in the image above.

Comment: If you want the margins and paddings displayed as in your images you're going to have to change your markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the following rule.  It seems to work.

```
.row.collapse {
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}
```

```css
.col-1 {
  background-color: blue;
}
.col-2 {
  background-color: green;
}
.col-3 {
  background-color: grey;
}

.row.collapse {
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.1/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row collapse">
  <div class="large-3 small-12 columns">
    <div class="row collapse">
      <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-12 columns col-1">
      The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
      </div>
      <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-12 columns col-2">
      The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="large-9 small-12 columns col-3">
  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for this solution! I ended up using foundation's `align-stretch` css class which provides the `flex-wrap` solution. this was very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Check out CSS Grid. It's literally only available in browsers (without enabling the flag) in the last week or two (as of the time of writing this answer) so this is a "use at your own risk" answer, but you may look into using it for this. It is simple enough layout that the older version that IE/Edge use should be viable.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .wrapper {
    grid-template-columns: 30% 70%;
  }
}
.col-1 {
  background-color: blue;
}
.col-2 {
  background-color: green;
}
.col-3 {
  background-color: grey;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-1 {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 1;
  }
  .col-2 {
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 1;
  }
  .col-3 {
    grid-column: 1 / span 2;
    grid-row: 2;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .col-1 {
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
    grid-row: 1;
  }
  .col-2 {
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
    grid-row: 2;
  }
  .col-3 {
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 1 / span 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.1/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="col-1">
    The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
  </div>
  <div class="col-2">
    The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. 
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
  </div>
</div>
```

Resources:

- http://gridbyexample.com/
- https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/01/css-grid
- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout

Answer (score 1):

As Joseph Marikle's answer points out, simply adding `display:flex;` and `flex-wrap:wrap` to your `.row.collapse` will get the desired positioning.

What his answer doesn't tell you is that the more difficult part in this solution is getting the margins and paddings to display correctly, as in your images. Here's what you need to add to it:

- wrap contents of each element inside a generic wrapper;
- add `display:flex` + `flex-direction:column` to both wrappers and their parent columns, as well as `flex-grow:1` to the wrappers;
- add padding to the outer `.row.collapse`;
- add margin to the wrappers;
- move the `background-color`s from columns to wrappers.

That's about it. Proof of concept: https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/xho9nzsk/